# Rotation operations in a red-black tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

Have been using Eric Roberts' Programming Abstractions textbook to strengthening DSA skills. There is an exercise to implement Red-Black tree. And there is a figure [Rotations in a red black tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdlKb.png)
I don't see why the tree on the left, which is a mirrored version of the tree on the right satisfy conditions for being a legitimate Red -Black tree. All paths from the root to a left must contain the same number of black nodes.
In the picture I highlighted the path with red. N2 -> N1 -> T3 gives us one black node, excluding null pointer T3. But N2 -> N1 -> N4 - highlighted with green gives two black nodes. Contradiction.
Must some other operations be performed on the left tree to make it satisfy all R-B trees properties?

Comment: T3 has a larger black-depth than the other *unspecified* subtrees.

Comment: As you said. T3 contains an extra black node.

Comment: And in Case 2, the whole illustration is wrong. T1 must contain an extra black node, but after rebalancing the 2nd diagram is no longer a RB Tree. The author of these diagrams needs to come up with better illustrations that conform.

Answer (score 1):

I am blind and so cannot comment directly on the pictures you've posted. However, when an insert or remove operation is performed the tree may (but need not) become imbalanced. Only when the insert or remove fix-up is complete are you guaranteed that the tree conditions will be valid. There is no sequence where a single rotation on a valid tree, by itself, will result in a different valid tree.

Are you certain that the graphic is not simply illustrating what is meant by the tree rotation operation without commenting on whether the resulting tree is valid?

Comment: The figure illustrates a rotation from red-left to red-right, and includes the necessary recoloring.